# Vue.js 3 optional v-scroll-to

Tags: vue.js, components, vuejs3

Here is the code that I use.

```html
<template>
  <div class="button-layout" :style="`margin: ${margin}; text-align: ${align};`">
    <component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons.filter(btn => btn.url)"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      v-scroll-to="button.url"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`" />
    <component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons.filter(btn => !btn.url)"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      :type="button.type"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ButtonLayout",
  components: {  },
  props: {
    button: String,
    margin: String,
    align: String,
    space: String,
    buttons: Array
  },
  computed: {
    buttonComponent() {
      return () => import(`./button/${this.button}`)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I can use these two list of object structures and it works fine.

```js
[
    { url: '#video', label: lang.video },
    { url: '#info', label: lang.info }
]
```

```js
[
    { type: 'reset', label: lang.clear },
    { type: 'submit', label: lang.send }
]
```

As I don't like repeating my code, I tried to add dynamically the attribute `type` and `v-scroll-to` based on the first object on the list, however, it doesn't work. What would be the best way to achieve it? (See the code below)

```html
<template>
  <div class="button-layout" :style="`margin: ${margin}; text-align: ${align};`">
    <component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      v-bind:[optionalDirective.directive]="button[optionalDirective.key]"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ButtonLayout",
  components: {  },
  props: {
    button: String,
    margin: String,
    align: String,
    space: String,
    buttons: Array
  },
  computed: {
    buttonComponent() {
      return () => import(`./button/${this.button}`)
    },
    optionalDirective(){
      if(this.buttons[0].url) {
        return {
          directive: 'v-scroll-to',
          key: 'url'
        }
      } else {
        return {
          directive: 'type',
          key: 'type'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `v-scroll-to` cannot be bound to `v-bind`, I found a little work around that actually solve my issue and avoid to duplicate the code twice. I bind the `@click` to a method that inspect the `url` value and `$scollTo` if needed, and it solve my problem.

```html
<template>
  <div class="button-layout" :style="`margin: ${margin}; text-align: ${align};`">
    <component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      v-bind="type(button.type)"
      @click="scrollTo(button.url)"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ButtonLayout",
  components: {},
  props: {
    button: String,
    margin: String,
    align: String,
    space: String,
    buttons: Array
  },
  methods: {
    type(type) {
      return type ? { type } : {}
    },
    scrollTo(url) {
      if (url) this.$scrollTo(url)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    buttonComponent() {
      return () => import(`./button/${this.button}`);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object to `v-bind` and it will create html attributes based on the keys of the object.

Something like this should work

```
<component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      v-bind="{[button.url ? 'v-scroll-to' : 'type' ] : (button.url || button.type} }"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`" />
```

Or you could declare a new method that returns the desired object

```
methods: {
  buttonDirective (button) {
   if (button.url) {
     return {
       'v-scroll-to': button.url
     }
   } else {
     return {
       'type': button.type
     }
   }
  }
}
```

and then call it in `component`

```
<component
      :is="buttonComponent"
      v-for="(button, index) in buttons"
      :key="button.label"
      :label="button.label"
      v-bind="buttonDirective(button)"
      :style="`margin-left: ${index === 0 ? '' : space};`" />
```

Comment: For a reason that I ignore, only the `type` is working. It seems like `v-scroll-to` cannot be `v-bind` such as `:v-scroll-to` by example.